# Ext.js: How to align button to left on header?

Tags: extjs

See fiddle here:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1u71

How to align "test" button to left on Extjs header?

When we delete the 'title' it renders as div tag with &nbsp content.
Please update solution because i have used "floating: true" which is moving the test button to left but complete header is in middle of page!

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                collapsible: true,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                header: {
                    titlePosition: 0,
                    title: "title",
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'test',
                        cls: 'lefty'
                    }]
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `tbspacer` block after the button xtype block to move button position to left. `width` is `%` value for responsive design.(You can keep `title` or remove)

```
    header: {
              items: [
                   {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'test ONE',
                    cls: 'lefty'
                   },
                   {
                    xtype:'tbspacer',
                    width: '80%' //change percentage to desired button position 
                   },
                   {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'test TWO',
                    cls: 'lefty'
                   },
              ],
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `titlePosition: 1` on your header. That will mean the button will go first, then the title, then the tools.

Comment: We are moving the 'title' position that is the reason it swaps `titlePosition:1` or `2` 
But how to place the buttons as left aligned or center aligned without changing the 'title' position.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Can you make a diagram and update your post?

Comment: Thank you @evan-trimboli !!. 
I found solution. I wanted to align the buttons location any where over the header and with responsive design.  I have added `tbspacer`  block after the button xtype block to move button position to left.
`{
   xtype:'tbspacer',
   width: '80%'     //change percentage to desired button position
  },`

Answer (score 0):

You can use config titlePosition to order items in header panel.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).